# Curl oAuth equivalent in Java

Tags: java, curl, heroku, oauth

I can't find the way to reproduce the following curl oAuth authentication call in Java:

```
curl 'https://id.herokuapp.com/oauth/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic AUTH_VALUE' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'  --data 'username=_USERNAME&password=_PASSWORD&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=_SECRET&client_id=_CLIENT_ID' --compressed
```

I don't know how to pass the `--data` value to the call.

Comment: This needs actual code so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using standard java.net.URL it can be done but the syntax is rather cumbersome, I suggest that you try using [HTTP Components library](http://hc.apache.org/). You should end up with something like this:

```
final HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
        .setUri("https://id.herokuapp.com/oauth/token")
        .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setHeader("Authorization", "Basic AUTH_VALUE")
        .addParameter("username", "_USERNAME")
        .addParameter("password", "_PASSWORD")
        .addParameter("grant_type", "password")
        .addParameter("scope", "read write")
        .addParameter("client_secret", "_SECRET")
        .addParameter("client_id", "_CLIENT_ID")
        .build();

final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
final HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity)); // or whatever processing you need
```

GZip/deflate and keep alive handling is provided out of the box if the HttpClient is created using HttpClientBuilder.